# How can i parse this respose to my Array of string

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

```
var mobileOprator = [String]() // My Array

//My Response
Optional("[\n  \"Aircel\",\n  \"Airtel\",\n  \"BSNL\",\n  \"Idea MTV\",\n  \"MTNL\",\n  \"MTS\",\n  \"Reliance CDMA\",\n  \"Reliance GSM\",\n  \"Reliance JIO\",\n  \"TATA CDMA\",\n  \"TATA DOCOMO\",\n  \"Telenor\",\n  \"Videocon\",\n  \"Vodafone\"\n]")
```

i want to parse it to my mobileOprator array.

Comment: `mobileOprator` is not an `Optional`, so the print show something else. Probably the result/return value of some function. Show more code.

Comment: Adding to shallowThought, if you are getting this from backend as JSON, then print whole JSON or post the url so that we can help you

Comment: mobileOprator is my Array , and the response i got after the API call  i want those data to be append in the mobileOprator Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Optional("[\n  \"Aircel\",\n  \"Airtel\",\n  \"BSNL\",\n  \"Idea MTV\",\n  \"MTNL\",\n  \"MTS\",\n  \"Reliance CDMA\",\n  \"Reliance GSM\",\n  \"Reliance JIO\",\n  \"TATA CDMA\",\n  \"TATA DOCOMO\",\n  \"Telenor\",\n  \"Videocon\",\n  \"Vodafone\"\n]")
```

is the same as this, just to visualize the data a little bit better

```
Optional("[  
              \"Aircel\",
              \"Airtel\",
              \"BSNL\",
              \"Idea MTV\",
              \"MTNL\",
              \"MTS\",
              \"Reliance CDMA\",
              \"Reliance GSM\",
              \"Reliance JIO\",
              \"TATA CDMA\",
              \"TATA DOCOMO\",
              \"Telenor\",
              \"Videocon\",
              \"Vodafone\"
            ]")
```

Since the data is optional it we should check if it exists and if it does start parsing. This can be done using the following syntax:

```
if let a = optional_a {

}
```

where `optional_a` can be any optional datatype and `a` is `nonoptional`. Basically Swift checks if it is `nil` and if not assigns it to `a`.

Next for the parsing, the String class has a function called `replacingOccurences(of: String!, with String!)`. Think of this as a find and replace all function. This can be used to remove any extraneous characters such as "\n", "\"", "\", "[", "]", and " ". Once these are removed we need to split the string with "," and map it into an array.

This code should work:

```
var optionalResponse = Optional("[\n  \"Aircel\",\n  \"Airtel\",\n  \"BSNL\",\n  \"Idea MTV\",\n  \"MTNL\",\n  \"MTS\",\n  \"Reliance CDMA\",\n  \"Reliance GSM\",\n  \"Reliance JIO\",\n  \"TATA CDMA\",\n  \"TATA DOCOMO\",\n  \"Telenor\",\n  \"Videocon\",\n  \"Vodafone\"\n]")
if var response = optionalResponse {
    let charsToRemove = ["\n", "\"", "\\", "[", "]", " "]
    for char in charsToRemove {
        response = response.replacingOccurrences(of: char, with: "")
    }
    let fullNameArr = response.characters.split{$0 == ","}.map(String.init)

    print(fullNameArr)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer it is the correct way, but i solved it by using **SwiftyJSON** . i will post the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

```
if let dataa = data as? String{
                if let dataFromString = dataa.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) {
                    let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)
                    for (_, val) in json {
                        self.mobileOprator.append(val.rawString()!)
                    }
                }
            }
```

In this way i got the Array i wanted, Used **SwiftyJSON** for parsing ..